# Expand wildcard in program's arguments

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, wildcard

I have batch file which attempts to launch a java application:

```
java -jar myProgram*.jar
```

I would like the batch file to evaluate the wildcard * in order to find the program regardless of version numbers. So it should find myProgram1.jar, or myProgram438.jar and run it.

But this batch file yields:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile myProgram*.jar
```

It looks like the arguments to java are not being processed by the shell. Is there a way to expand the wildcard in the arguments before passing them? I know that Bash has backtics which could do this. Is it possible to do in windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are more program*.jar in the folder you have to specify, which you want to start. The script starts the "last found":

```
@echo off&setlocal
for %%i in (myProgram*.jar) do set "jarProg=%%~i"
java -jar %jarProg%
```

You don't need "Cygwin" for this.